# No routes matched location when I use params

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling data from a file called 'data.js' into the component 'OurWork.jsx', and everything works fine since the file 'OurWork.jsx' shows all the data objects.
But anytime I want to click the more info button to show the detail of that specific object id, I got the following error:

[image]

This is my App.js where I have all my routes:

```
//Styles
import "./styles/basic.scss";

//Router
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

//import pages
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import OurWork from "./components/OurWork";
import ContactUs from "./components/ContactUs";
import SingleWork from "./components/SingleWork";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/work" element={<OurWork />} />
        <Route path="/work/:workId" element={<SingleWork />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactUs />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my OurWork.jsx component which shows perfectly fine all the data:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import works from '../data';

function OurWork() {
  return (
    <section className='layout'>
        <h1>Works</h1>
        <div className="works">
          {works.map((work) => {
            return (
              <article key={work.id}>
                <h5>{work.name}</h5>
                <Link to={`/works/${work.id}`}>more info</Link>
              </article>
            );
          })}
        </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default OurWork;
```

And this is my SingleWork.jsx which needs to be rendered with the detail.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function SingleWork() {

  const { workId } = useParams();

  return (
    <div className='layout'>
        <h2>{workId}</h2>
        <Link to='/work'>Back to Works</Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SingleWork;
```

This is my data file:

```
const works = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Sticker in the wall',
        image: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/82TpEld0_e4'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Woman with cap',
        image: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/a-woman-standing-in-front-of-a-blue-stadium-5lHRsryQHe8'
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        name: 'The Island',
        image: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/NvL3xrjEX3k'
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        name: 'Woman with red globes at night',
        image: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/a-woman-holding-a-bunch-of-red-balloons-PJZd4t6Nfhc'
    },
    {
        id: '5',
        name: 'Yoga class',
        image: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/wfsgDFb-wK0'
    }
]

export default works;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're linking to the wrong path:

works vs work

Link to={`/works/${work.id}`}>more info

Comment: You are right!!